# How to get addresses and them coordinates from Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

**Task**: create input fieldwith auto complete addresses input. In example, user input `5 Gr...`, field must propose input:

`5 Green Avenue, Apt. 3
5 Gray Avenue, Apt. 1B
...`

In addition, application creates for Georgia and must has adressess with geogican.

---

In Internet I found more variants with using another service for get addresses and them coodinates, but I think, that better use Google Maps addresses for Google Maps.

So, how I can take all addresses from one city (Tbilisi) with them coordinates from Google Maps services (if it's not real, than from another service)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has done it for you ;)
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete